# Best program to batch compress JPGs with minimal loss?

Tags: jpeg, batch, windows, image-compression

My photo catalog is getting bigger and bigger. It's mainly my fault because in my noob years I used to export **all JPGs with a 100% quality**, point at which files can reach the 10mb mark or even more. I still do, I don't know why :F

Right now I'm at 600gb and I good chunk of it is because I keep RAW files, but JPGs are quite large and could be reduced.

What software do you use to **batch compress files**? I'm looking for a maximum quality solution -I know there's no lossless in JPG, but what is the least lossy one, in terms of quality.

So far I found https://imageoptim.com/ which unfortunately it's a Mac only solution. I tried ImageMagik also but I can't manage to get the correct settings, mainly because is command line based.

Comment: @Andres - when I want to share files, I have to find them first.  It's far easier to find in Lightroom than in bare files on the computer.  I can do a quick filter, select my options and export at an appropriate quality level for my intended distribution quickly.  Saving them off as large JPEGs isn't needed.  Also, if you have a LR catalog, just do another export from LR at whatever quality level you want them at.  It sounds like you have more workflow problems than storage problems.

Comment: I actually think you should keep them at 100%. More on this [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/57484/1943). If you need a specific image at a lower size to share, create it as needed.

Answer (score 4):

[JPEGmini](http://www.jpegmini.com/). It's $20 for the full version, but you can trial it (as a test of quality) for free. The trial version (or, rather, the unactivated version) has a 20-image-per-day cap — no time bomb, though, so someone with different needs may never have to pay for it. The full version can recompress entire directories at a go.

It'll take most large high-quality JPEGS down to 20-25% of their file size (some more, some less) and you really need to do an image subtraction to see that it's made any change to the actual image at all. ("Large" means up to 28MP; if you've got a D800/D810/α7R or a medium-format camera and have left the JPEGs at your camera's full resolution, you'd have to spring for the "pro" version, and I'm not sure it's still cost-effective at the "pro" price.) It'll also do a batch resize at the same time if you want to do that.

It's slow as the proverbial molasses in January to load (it's a .NET application, and sort of feels like loading a full-featured Eclipse-based IDE), but it runs at an acceptable pace once it *has* finally loaded. (The "pro" version is considerably faster, but see the price issue mentioned above. Nothing's ever fast enough when you're doing a big job, but once the big job is over, you're left wondering why there's a Veyron in the driveway when all you use it for now is to go to the corner store for milk a couple of times a week.)

But do trial it on a few images before you buy — even cheap is expensive if it doesn't do what you want. The opinions of random weirdos on teh intarwebz ar often worth less than you paid for them. Oh, one more thing: the license fulfillment is done through B&H, so it's not instant. (Someone at B&H, lovingly known through the ages as "Kosher Kamera", has to press a button or something to make sure that you can't get it on Sabbath or a no-work-allowed holiday accidentally. Weird choice for a sole retailer of an electronically-delivered product in my opinion, but it's the choice they made.)

(No affiliation, just an otherwise satisfied customer who *really wonders* about the B&H part.)

Comment: I am not sore if it is advertisement, but is just another software to compress to jpeg. Above in comment to the question we mention two free alternatives which I am sure can do the same. Free of charge!

Comment: It doesn't convert *to* JPEG, it optimizes compression of existing JPEGs. I specifically said trial it, and if it works you might want to buy it. (I also pointed out its most annoying problems and limitations, which are not usually part of an advertisement.) And it does optimized/segmented compression that doesn't leave any artifacts behind (the OP stated that quality was an issue), which ImageMagick doesn't do.

Comment: The only way to "optimize" compression is to recode/convert the file. So from my point this software just convert jpeg to jpeg. And I am sure you know ImageMagic can be tuned to use particular quality/level of compression to reach acceptable level of target image

Comment: Hahaha B&H and sabbath comment made me laugh. Very true indeed.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - no, you can use different levels of compression for different blocks of the image and use different block sizes within the image; the JPEG standard allows for that, and I don't know of an application that can't read the files. If you can tell the difference (visually) between an original Q100 JPEG (12 in Photoshop) and one that been through an optimizer to take it down to 25% of the file size, you have much better eyes than I do. On the other hand, bringing the quality down to 70 does leave visible artifacts (that may or may not be objectionable at a given image size).

Comment: @user35658, I think you do not understand the idea behind my expression about recode/convert. I know about the blocks and so on, but this is named convert because it change totally the file/image. About the eyes: Hm, there is one point which can help me to see what you can't see, I am colour blind and one side effect of this is I have "higher resolution" of the eyes. So I can see details most people can't :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov - don't bet on that, I have exceptional acuity. And this *is not the same* as running the image through ImageMagick to recompress (although it is a very good match for JpegOptim; they're comparable). Look, just try the free program and see what I'm talking about. I'm not connected with the software, and have nothing to gain from this recommendation except, maybe, the thanks of the people who try it and find it suits their needs.

Comment: JPEGmini works by adaptively changing the compression levels used _within_ the image — see [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/16737/1943). But, further, see [this answer to a different question about bulk recompression](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/24027/1943), which demonstrates that this really doesn't provide much practical benefit over just using worse global parameters.

Comment: It fundamentally dpends on how compressable the image is (or, rather, how compressable *parts of the image* are). You don't need contrived examples; a typical portrait will have both areas of tight detail that won't stand much compression and areas that can be crunched down to nothing. *Worst case*, they work out about the same (and Russel's right about the 85-ish value being more-or-less the acceptable artifacting cut-off), but best-case JPEGmini (or equivalent, I'm not *pushing* a product) can be much smaller. I've found the difference valuable, YMMV.

Comment: currently $59 ...

Answer (score 3):

If you are not afraid of using the command line, [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is the tool you need. It is the state of the art of image processing and it is widely recognized as THE software for image processing.

In your specific case, you are interested in changing what ImageMagick refers to [`-quality value`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality). Since a similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784057/run-a-simple-command-using-powershell-recursively-on-a-directory#784067) I will just cover the needed adaptations for your specific question.

```
dir -recurse -include *.jpg | %{convert  $_.FullName -quality 80 "C:\processed\$_"}
```

Where **you need** to substitute the quality value (in this example 80) to your preferred compression level *and* the output directory `C:\processed\` to suit your needs.

This method will essentially duplicate all your photos (even though compressed) to the specified path. In the case that you do not have enough disk space for such operation, you can use the [`mogrify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) command that will overwrite everything that is present in the output path with the same filename. Be aware that it is a **dangerous** operation because there is no going back and if you ever need to perform such action it is better to first try it on a dozen backupped photos and once ensured that the output is as desired you can safely run it over your catalog.

So if you `mogrify` some photos (with the output path specified) and you are not happy with the result you can safely re-run the command with a different quality value and the photos in the output directory will be overwritten.

I'm available to elaborate more on `mogrify` if needed but basically, you just need to swap the `convert`.

Comment: OP said, _I tried ImageMagik also but I can't manage to get the correct settings, mainly because is command line based._ So it sounds like OP isn't interested in ImageMagick. However, kudos for details explaining the use of IM, rather than just "try tool X". +1

Comment: Yeah that's why I thought that providing more in depth example usage could ease the use of the command line for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop will certainly do this, and quite well.

You can easily achieve it by saving an action with the steps you desire and can even save it as a droplet that to be used on demand very easily.

This has more information on Photoshops capabilities in this area: http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html

Comment: Of course, PS can do the job, but if you want to convert 10k of images in different directories this can be no so strait process. IMHO software, offered above can be better choise

Comment: Romeo - The question doesn't say anything about different directories does it? I think I've answered the question.

Comment: @dpollitt Actually yes, those pictures are across different directories.

Comment: Well PS can certainly still do it across multiple directories but it may become cumbersome depending on the number. It would be great if the question had the info we needed to answer it. The fact that it's 10k images does not matter, PS can do that. If it's 10k directories something else would likely be better.